# execute 'mpicc -std=c11 solution.c -o solution' error with MPI Paralles Computer

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

when I executed 'mpicc -std=c11 solution.c -o solution' on my Mac, then it showed unix execute file, but when I clicked it, error folloing happaned.
Does anybody know what's wrong?

```
(base) fire@liuyanhengdeMacBook-Pro ~ % /Users/fire/assignment/solution ; exit;
Assertion failed: (f != NULL), function parse_menu, file solution.c, line 158.
[liuyanhengdeMacBook-Pro:16864] *** Process received signal ***
[liuyanhengdeMacBook-Pro:16864] Signal: Abort trap: 6 (6)
[liuyanhengdeMacBook-Pro:16864] Signal code:  (0)
[liuyanhengdeMacBook-Pro:16864] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff6cb645fd _sigtramp + 29
[liuyanhengdeMacBook-Pro:16864] [ 1] 0   solution                            0x000000010b65a118 _dyld_private + 16504
[liuyanhengdeMacBook-Pro:16864] [ 2] 0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff6ca3a808 abort + 120
[liuyanhengdeMacBook-Pro:16864] [ 3] 0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff6ca39ac6 err + 0
[liuyanhengdeMacBook-Pro:16864] [ 4] 0   solution                            0x000000010b651b60 parse_menu + 96
[liuyanhengdeMacBook-Pro:16864] [ 5] 0   solution                            0x000000010b65130a main + 170
[liuyanhengdeMacBook-Pro:16864] [ 6] 0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6c96bcc9 start + 1
[liuyanhengdeMacBook-Pro:16864] *** End of error message ***
zsh: abort      /Users/fire/assignment/solution
```

Following is my parse_menu function.And I have tested the menu.tsv file that is can read and write.

```
static void parse_menu(int *menu) {
    FILE* f = fopen("menu.tsv", "r");
    assert(f != NULL);

    int n_items = 0;
    for (;;) {
        int index;
        // ignore the name; store the prices
        int parsed = fscanf(f, "%d %*s %d", &index, &menu[n_items]);
        if (parsed != 2) {
            // No more items to parse.
            break;
        }

        n_items++;
    }
    assert(n_items == ITEMS_ON_MENU);

    fclose(f);
}
```

Maybe it is a small error in the above code preventing this function, but I cannot seem to find the issue.

Comment: Does the file even exist? did you mean `menu.csv` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it failed to open your file :

`Assertion failed: (f != NULL), function parse_menu, file solution.c, line 158.`

Maybe an error in the name of your file ? You wrote `menu.tsv`, maybe you meant `menu.csv` ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Didn't see your comment there, sorry about that. I'll delete my post and you can make one

Comment: Don't bother, I am not the only one able to guess such a typo :-)